# AsyncFileUpload is not accepting larger images

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I am trying to upload an image of size 800kb using Ajax AsyncFileupload control

But on the server side the filebytes are null if the image size is large.

can any body tell me the possible solution for uploading larger documents using AsyncFileUpload control.

thanking you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to web.config in   section `</system.web>`

```
    <!-- maximum upload file size (KB) -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="100000" />
```